# Can "ne" replace the agent in "far fare" constructions?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

In a sentence like

> Mi sono fatto riparare la macchina da Stefano.

is it possible to replace the complemento d'agente with *ne* as in

> Me ne sono fatto riparare la macchina.

? I cannot find any examples for such usage but I don't see why it should be impossible in these types of constructions.

Comment: The pronoun *ne* is a genitive form and that's why the usage is impossible.

Comment: @egreg, I was going to answer along similar lines, but then realised that _ne_ may also have a “_da_” meaning (_ne sono appena tornato_), also applied to people (_è sempre stato scortese con lei, ma non ne ha mai ottenuto che gentilezze_). The last example is from [De Mauro's dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ne), which in the entry “_ne_” gives, among other meanings, “con riferimento a persone: da lui, da lei, da parte sua, da loro, da parte loro”. This said, I agree that using _ne_ as complemento d'agente sounds strange.

Comment: I agree that the use of 'ne' in the OP's sentence is strange, and I think incorrect. But the question of the use of 'ne' as complemento di agente  is complicate, and strange, as I se in https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/usi-della-particella-ne/138. For instance, one cas say " Ho visto Mario e ne sono rimasto colpito" , ma non si può dire, mi pare, "Ho visto Mario e ne sono stato picchiato".

Comment: @BakerStreet Right, it seems (and [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ne1/) and Zingarelli (paywall) indirectly confirm) that the _da_-meaning of _ne_ applies to things more than to people, as your Mario examples point out (in the first sentence I understand that what struck me was meeting Mario, rather than Mario himself).

Answer (score -1):

> Mi sono fatto fare un tatuaggio al polpaccio. Me ne (tatuaggio) sono fatto fare uno anche al bicipite.

"Ne" is used as placeholder for a noun previously mentioned.

In your example ne isn't necessary because the noun (macchina) is right there in the sentence.

In the reflexive form can be found in those situations like "me ne vado", "non ne posso più", "aversene a male", "non volermene", "na ha fatte di cotte e di crude" etc.

Comment: Be careful: the OP's sentence is tricky but, if anything, _ne_ doesn't refer to _macchina_ but to Stefano or whomever fixed the car.

Comment: I see... anyway the use he gives is not idiomatic. Should I delete my answer?